# How to set up a dummy service that runs at certain hours of the day?

Tags: services, macos

I use a program called [Jiggler](http://www.sticksoftware.com/software/Jiggler.html) to prevent my MacBook from going to sleep. However, I only want Jiggler to do this between certain hours of the day, such as 9-5.

Jiggler doesn't have such a setting in its preferences. However, it has an option to only Jiggle if "[An application | A process] is running whose name contains...". So I imagine I can set up a background process, that does nothing, but has a unique name and simply runs between 9-5. Then I can use that to make Jiggler only work during those times.

How can I set up such a background process? For example, on Linux one may create a systemd service - is there an analogous thing on OS X?

Comment: Have you tried to raise a feature request at https://github.com/bhaller/Jiggler ?

Comment: @nohillside There is already a similar feature request: https://github.com/bhaller/Jiggler/issues/20 It seems unlikely that it will be added to the program soon. Besides, the question is about setting up a background process at certain times of day, not Jiggler specifically.